# How to add a + button in a react native screen - Error:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MyTabs from './navigation/AppNavigator';

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

THen:

StorageListScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import StorageScreen from './StorageScreen'; // Import the StorageScreen component

const StorageListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>List of Storages</Text>

      {/* Display the list of storages here */}
      {/* You can retrieve and display the data from your storage system */}

      <Button
        title="Add Storage"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('StorageScreen')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
});

export default StorageListScreen;
```

The storage list screen will render a list of storages, the idea is to have a + button on the bottom right, which should navigate to the Storage screen which is a form with 2 fields.

StorageScreen.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const StorageScreen = () => {
  const [storageName, setStorageName] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');

  const saveData = () => {
    // You can implement logic to save the data to your storage system here
    console.log('Storage Name:', storageName);
    console.log('Location:', location);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Storage Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => setStorageName(text)}
        value={storageName}
        placeholder="Enter Storage Name"
      />

      <Text style={styles.label}>Location</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => setLocation(text)}
        value={location}
        placeholder="Enter Location"
      />

      <Button title="Save" onPress={saveData} />

      {/* You can add more components or styles as needed */}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 16,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
});

export default StorageScreen;
```

However I get this error:

```
ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"StorageScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'StorageScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

Update:
I forgot to include my app navigator

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'; // Import the HomeScreen component
import YourFood from '../screens/YourFood'; // Import the HomeScreen component
import StorageListScreen from '../screens/StorageListScreen'; // Import the HomeScreen component

import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Storage"
        component={StorageListScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Storage',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="fridge-variant" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Your Food"
        component={YourFood}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Food',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="food-variant" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
export default MyTabs;
```

Comment: You never use `StorageScreen`

Comment: I don't see `StorageScreen` in your config. I see `Storage` on the other hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you MUST add StorageScreen to the stack container, read more here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

UPDATE:
for example, `StorageScreen` must inside the Stack list to make it's can be handled by Navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="StorageScreen" component={StorageScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: In my original question I forgot to add the code of the appnavigator, which is some bottom tabs, already in a navigator object.

Basically I have a bottom menu, when opening one of the options, I need a button inside that screen